# Programmatically Added View Pager doesn't display

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

i added viewpager for image sliding programmatically but my viewpager doesnot display. i added viewpager inflating the xml file.

Here's my code.

**Added viewpager**

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_view_pager,null);
                ViewPager pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
                pager.setId(View.generateViewId());

                FullBannerViewPager adapter = new FullBannerViewPager(getContext(),fullBannerModels.get(fullBannerCount));
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                llMainLayout.addView(view);
```

**custom_view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:background="@color/dokaan_red">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ASDFASDFAS FSD FASDF"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**here's my adapter FullBannerViewPager.java**

```
package com.hazesoft.dokan.dashboard.view.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.hazesoft.dokan.R;
import com.hazesoft.dokan.dashboard.view.Model.DashboardFullBannerModel;
import com.hazesoft.dokan.singleproductdetail.GalleryActivity;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FullBannerViewPager extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<DashboardFullBannerModel> fullBannerModels;

    public FullBannerViewPager(Context context, List<DashboardFullBannerModel> fullBannerModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.fullBannerModels = fullBannerModels;
        Log.d("fullbannermodel", "FullBannerViewPager: "+new Gson().toJson(fullBannerModels));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fullBannerModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return  view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup view, int position, Object object) {
        view.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.full_banner_view_pager, collection, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.full_banner);
        Picasso.with(context).load(fullBannerModels.get(position).getImage()).into(imageView);

        collection.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;

    }
}
```

**full_banner_view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_195sdp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/full_banner"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/aa"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here inflating view is ok but viewpager is not showing.

Comment: Why are you overriding the pager ID if already have one? `pager.setId(View.generateViewId());` but previously you called `ViewPager pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);` so the pager has the ID `R.id.viewPager`.

Comment: i have try with removing .setId but doesnt work whether it is in there and if not there but all the data are set to the adapter but doesnt show the view

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i solved by creating one of the view in viewpager and after the viewpager is set and remove the view. 
Here's code

**custom_view_pager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_195sdp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_195sdp"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/aa"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
 View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_view_pager,null);
                    ViewPager pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
                    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    FullBannerViewPager adapter = new FullBannerViewPager(getContext(),fullBannerModels.get(fullBannerCount));
                    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    llMainLayout.addView(view);

                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```